# how to switch tabs back by keyboard in latest firefox (27)?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

I wonder is it a bug or a 'feature' that standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcuts to move between tabs in backwards are disabled.

In `about:config` I have set: `browser.ctrlTab.previews;true`, but it doesn't work.  It is showing the previews but I can move only forward. Also, extensions like [Ctrl-Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ctrl-tab/) and [Super Tab Mode](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/super-tab-mode/) do not work.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> seems to switch between fields in a form on a web page or between links or some other elements.  This shortcut is working fine in Opera and Chrome. Only FireFox has problems here.

Are there any other keyboard shortcuts introduced instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or I'm forced here to use the mouse ?

Comment: What's the operating system? I can't reproduce the issue using Firefox 27.0.1 on Windows 7: both Ctrl+Shift+Tab and Ctrl+Page Up works. All available shortcuts are listed in this KB article: [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).

Comment: XP SP3, sorry I forgot that might be the issue ? In beta 28 both forward and backward tab switching do not work.

Comment: Just tried: works in Windows XP SP3 too. Did you try the alternate keyboard shortcut? Do you get the same issue in [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)? Let's focus on the stable versions, anyway.

Comment: Ok when I have table previews on, then using ctrl+tab launches the preview window and then holding control when I press shift the thing is going correctly backwards. So first forward and then from the level of the preview window the backwards option is accesible. But there is no way to move back one tab directly with ctrl+shift+tab. And I feel that they are messing more with the code here so in 28 there are more issues with this feature (tab previews do not work).

Comment: That question is irrelevant now, that was a bug in that particular version of Firefox then. Now is all working fine.